# compound Index or single index in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I got a query like this that gets called 90% of the times:

db.xyz.find({ "ws.wz.eId" : 665 , "ws.ce1.id" : 665)

and another one like this that gets called 10% of the times:

db.xyz.find({ "ws.wz.eId" : 111 , "ws.ce2.id" : 111)

You can see that the id for the two collections in both queries are the same.
Now I'm wondering if I should just create a single index just for "ws.wz.eId" or if I should create two compound indexes: one for {"ws.wz.eId", "ws.ce.id"} and another one for {"ws.wz.eId", "ws.ce2.id"}

It seems to me that the single index is the best choice; however I might be wrong; so I would like to know if there is value in creating the compound index, or any other type.

Comment: you could create the indexes, run an explain on your queries and see the effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As muratgu already pointed out, the best way to reason about performance is to stop reasoning and start measuring instead.

However, since measurements can be quite tricky, here's some theory:

You might want to consider *one* compound index `{"ws.wz.eId", "ws.ce1.id"}` because that can be used for the 90% case and, for the ten percent case, is equivalent to just having an index on `ws.wz.eId`.

When you do this, the first query can be matched through the index, the second query will have to find all candidates with matching `ws.wz.eId` first (fast, index present) and then scan-and-match all candidates to filter out those documents that don't match the `ws.ce2.id` criterion. Whether that is expensive or not depends on the number of documents with same `ws.wz.eId` that must be scanned, so this depends very much on your data.

An important factor is the selectivity of the key. For example, if there's a million documents with same `ws.wz.eId` and only one of those has the `ws.ce2.id` you're looking for, you might need the index, or want to reverse the query.